# Is it possible to call page.screenshot in headless chrome on each frame

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, requestanimationframe

Using Nodejs and headless chrome I am trying to record a javascript animation as a png sequence.

The animation is controlled via one or several `requestanimationframe` methods.

```
function AnimRenderer () {
  do stuff;
  requestAnimationFrame(AnimRenderer);
}
```

How can I call an await `page.screenshot()` on each frame?

I managed to record a sequence with `phantomjs`. Now I am trying to do it with headless chrome. I used Timesnap https://github.com/tungs/timesnap which is a great tool but I found it to be to slow this is why I am trying to use headless chrome.